# Do these higher-dimensional analogues of Möbius transformations have a name?

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, lie-groups

Do maps of the form
$$
x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \frac{Ax+b}{c^Tx+d} \in \mathbb{R}^n,
$$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, b, c \in \mathbb{R}^n, d\in \mathbb{R}$ have a name? Have they been studied anywhere?

It looks somehow familiar to Möbius-transformation but it is different as $A, b, c, d$ are not complex numbers.

It is easy to see that the above maps form a group.

I am interested in this because of an application in optics where I found that for a thin lense the map which maps image to object points is of the above form. I am especially interested in the $n=2$ and $n=3$ cases.

Comment: The above map is only defined at $x$ if $c^Tx+d\neq 0$. So there should be some condition on $(A,b,c,d)$ to avoid the image to be contained in a hyperplane (since otherwise the composition would be ill-defined).

Comment: They're called (real) projective transformations, or homographies.

Comment: @YCor: regardless from conditions on the denominators, they could be seen as elements of the group of birational automorphisms of real projective space.

Comment: @Qfwfq regardless from conditions on denominators? which birational transformation do you recognize when $(A,b,c,d)=(0,0,0,0)$?

Comment: If these encode homographies, the condition is probably that the determinant of $\begin{pmatrix}A & b\\c^T & d\end{pmatrix}$ is nonzero.

Comment: @YCor: I explained myself poorly; I meant: you don't have to consider only the points $x$ for which the denominator is nonzero, or to only consider those data $(A,b,c,d)$ for which the map is defined set theoretically at *all* points.

Comment: @Qfwfq I know, but the OP wrote explicitly that the value should belong to $\mathbf{R}^n$. And even for $(c,d)=(0,1)$ for which there is no definition ambiguity (one gets $x\mapsto Ax+b$), it can fail to define a birational transformation (if $\det(A)=0$).

Answer (score 11):

These seem to be [projective transformations / homographies / collineations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography#Definition_and_expression_in_homogeneous_coordinates). See particularly the formulas given when projective spaces are defined by adding points at infinity to affine spaces.

This is no surprise since there is a long history of projective geometry in optics, going back to the study of [perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspectivity). I think you are probably already aware of this, but these maps provide a good description of image transformations by lenses only in the [paraxial approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraxial_approximation).

[Here's a chapter by Douglas S. Goodman](http://photonics.intec.ugent.be/education/IVPV/res_handbook/v1ch01.pdf) from the Optical Society of America's [*Handbook of Optics*](http://photonics.intec.ugent.be/education/IVPV/res_handbook/) which contains a discussion of these transformations in Section 1.15 (page 59 of the PDF, page 1.60 in the internal numbering of the book). It seems the preferred terminology in optics is "collineation"; note however that [Wikipedia distinguishes collineations from homographies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collineation#Types), though they agree for real projective spaces.

Comment: I see now that Gro-Tsen has posted a comment to the same effect and that the question has picked up a vote to close. I'm happy to delete this answer if others feel it's not necessary.

Comment: ... the question could be moved to MathSE too and the answer would be useful too.

Comment: @YCor that sounds fine to me. I will vote for migration.